# WordPress Real Cron Job Returns Empty Site Options

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have developed a WordPress site that has disabled the standard wp_cron and implemented a real cron job. The cron is set up as follows:

`“c:\Program files\php\php.exe” E:\SiteRootFolder\wpcron.php`

This appears to work perfectly. However, when the cron fires and runs code in the functions file, WordPress functions such as `home_url`, `wp_get_attachment_image_src`, `get_permalink`, `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` and other either don't work (return empty) or return odd values (`get_stylesheet_directory_uri` returns `http:///wp-content/themes/theme-folder-name` instead of properly including the url). However, other functions like `$wpdb->get_results($querystr)` and `wp_get_post_terms` for example) seem to work fine.

When I run the functions from within the WordPress admin (I added a button to fire the functions so that the admin could fire the job on demand), everything works perfectly. But when it runs from the real cron job, all these important functions break.

What is the reason for this? Is there a reference to a file that is missing when the real cron runs?

Comment: to be expected. you're running it from the command line, so all the various $_SERVER parameters that are normally set when run via a webserver are not available, and wp loses much of its context.

Comment: @MarcB, do you have a suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `wp-cron.php` from your web-server context, not directly using the PHP executable. Here is a page on some of the details of [disabling the default WP-Cron](http://justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress/disable-wp-cron-wordpress/), written for CentOS, but you can use [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) for Windows for the same results.

In short your cron job should look similar to the following assuming your domain is `example.com` and wanted to run WP-Cron every 5 minutes. This will call `wp-cron.php` with all the proper `$_SERVER` variables defined required to give the expected values from many of the WordPress functions.

`*/5 * * * * curl.exe --silent http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`

Comment: If anyone needs more information regarding the cron code above, visit http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/301-run-cron-job